# No content to map due to end-of-input jackson parser

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am getting this response from the server `{"status":"true","msg":"success"}`

I am trying to parse this json string using Jackson parser library but somehow I am facing mapping-exception stating

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@421ea4c0; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Why do we get this kind of exceptions?

How to understand what is causing this exception?

I am trying to parse using following way:

```
StatusResponses loginValidator = null;

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);

try {
    String res = result.getResponseAsString();//{"status":"true","msg":"success"}
    loginValidator = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponseAsString(), StatusResponses.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**StatusResponse class**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "status","msg" })
public class StatusResponses {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    private String message;

    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonSetter
    public void setAdditionalProperties(Map<String, Object> additionalProperties) {
        this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
    }
}
```

Comment: This can also be caused due to a connection timeout. If the client is expecting a response from the server, but the HTTP connector has a timeout period that is exceeded - it will return  a "blank" response for the timeout - which can cause this error message when trying to parse into json. The fix to this will vary - but increasing the timeout period is one temp fix.

Comment: what was the type of `result`? Could it be that calling `getResponseAsString` on `result` two times is the issue due to the type of `result`? Eg Iterators in many languages cannot be traversed twice.

Comment: You should change this line `loginValidator = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponseAsString(), StatusResponses.class);` to `(res, ...)`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

StatusResponses loginValidator = null;

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);

try {
    String res = result.getResponseAsString();//{"status":"true","msg":"success"}
    loginValidator = objectMapper.readValue(res, StatusResponses.class);//replaced result.getResponseAsString() with res
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't know how it worked and why it worked? :( but it worked

Comment: Think that is because when you call getResponseAsString() it read all bytes from response and close connection. That's why it may throw exception

Comment: This works because of the String res you replaced and not because of Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE ....

Comment: I think you deserve Upvote for "Dont know how it worked and why it worked? :( but it worked" Honest fallow... Salute....

Comment: @Koloritnij I think your comment is wrong: `this method can be called several times yielding the same result each time`

Comment: This didn't solve the problem on my side but showed the real problem :). Therefore it still helped :).

Comment: API documentation says "Feature is enabled by default."

Answer (score 13):

In my case the problem was caused by my passing a null InputStream to the ObjectMapper.readValue call:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = ...
InputStream is = null; // The code here was returning null.
Foo foo = objectMapper.readValue(is, Foo.class)
```

I am guessing that this is the most common reason for this exception.

Comment: My reason was an empty string. Same thing

Comment: how to fix this null inputstream?

Answer (score 9):

I could fix this error. In my case, the problem was at client side. By mistake I did not close the stream that I was writing to server. I closed stream and it worked fine. Even the error sounds like server was not able to identify the end-of-input.

```
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(jsonstring.getBytes());
out.close() ; //This is what I did
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem for me was that I read the response twice as follows:

```java
System.out.println(response.body().string());
getSucherResponse = objectMapper.readValue(response.body().string(), GetSucherResponse.class);
```

However, the response can only be read once as it is a stream.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error today and the issue was the content-type header of the post request. Make sure the content type is what you expect. In my case a `multipart/form-data` content-type header was being sent to the API instead of `application/json`.

Comment: With curl you can add content-type like this:
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://www.myurl.com/

Answer (score 6):

This error is sometimes (often?) hiding the real problem: a failure condition could be causing the content to be incorrect, which then fails to deserialize.

In my case, today, I was making HTTP calls and (foolishly) omitted to check the HTTP status code before trying to unmarshal the body of the response => my real problem was actualy that I had some authentication error, which caused a `401 Unauthorized` to be sent back to me, with an empty body. Since I was unmarshalling that empty body directly without checking anything, I was getting this `No content to map due to end-of-input`, without getting any clue about the authentication issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when sending a GET request with postman.
The request required no parameters.
My mistake was I had a blank line in the request body.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was reading the stream in a jersey RequestEventListener I created on the server side to log the request body prior to the request being processed. I then realized that this probably resulted in the subsequent read to yield no string (which is what is passed over when the business logic is run). I verified that to be the case.

So if you are using streams to read the JSON string be careful of that.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix could be `Content-Type: application/json`

You are probably making a REST API call to get the response.

Mostly you are not setting  `Content-Type: application/json` when you the request. 
`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` will be chosen which might be causing this exception.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is weird but when I changed **GetMapping** to **PostMapping** for both client and server side the error disappeared.

Both client and server are Spring boot projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had race condition between 2 threads trying to write and read the file simultaneously. I added the "synchronized" keyword on my methods which writes and reads to the file and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Please Don't overthink this issue, simply handle the null pointer exception here as your response is received null and you will get your solution.

Comment: Please add your answer as a comment or improve it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31477474)

Answer (score 0):

I took your code to verify it and the only way you get the error is by sending it like this

```
String res = "";
```

Which is different than

```
String res = null;
```

So you can fix it by adding the following

```
if (res == null || res.length() < 1){
    //Handle however you want to handle it.
    System.out.println("RES CANNOT BE EMPTY or NULL.");
}
```

Naturally your res string must be a valid json string that can be mapped to the class you send in (in this case StatusResponses.class) but you need to encapsulate in a try/catch.  Catch "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input" or in your case "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException". but if you just catch exception you can handle as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If input stream is already used before desired call, it can not be reused again.
An example :

```
try (InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/resources/attributes.json") ) {
        // We're using input stream !
        String jsonContent = IOUtils.toString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        // We want to use input stream again
        // and it cases error : 
        // com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
        //                No content to map due to end-of-input

        // We must delete or comment upper line : String jsonContent = IOUtils.toString...
        var result = om.readValue(is, new TypeReference<List<BehaviouralAttribute>>() {});
```

Answer (score -2):

For one, `@JsonProperty("status")` and `@JsonProperty("msg")` should only be there only when declaring the fields, not on the setters and geters.

In fact, the simplest way to parse this would be

```
@JsonAutoDetect  //if you don't want to have getters and setters for each JsonProperty
public class StatusResponses {

   @JsonProperty("status")
   private String status;

   @JsonProperty("msg")
   private String message;

}
```

Comment: but how will this solve the mapping exception? And without getters and setters how can i access the arsed values for further use?

Comment: You can still add the getters and setters without the annotation. I think your annotation are confusing the mapper.