# When changed URL getting JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: java, json, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have the following code to get response as String and Object

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClient();
   CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, post)) {
   String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
   ResponseVO responseVO = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseString, ResponseVO.class);
```

It's working for specific URL, after changed the URL, I'm getting the following error (getting empty response):

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 0]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:255)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3851)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3792)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2797)
```

My ResponseVO:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResponseVO {
    @JsonProperty("isBlocked")
    private boolean blocked;
    private String responseId;
    //getters and setters
```

Do I need to add checks on `responseString`? check only not empty? what about invalid response? can/should I create an empty object in case of an error?

Other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925058/no-content-to-map-due-to-end-of-input-jackson-parser) are not relevant to my case

Comment: I think it is happening because the `responseString` is returning `null` so the mapping of JSON string to Java objects cannot happen. Maybe you need to add a null check.

Comment: @robot_alien it's empty, can I handle invalid input using ObjectMapper properties?