# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: java, openapi-generator

I am using generator with `<generatorName>java</generatorName>`, `<library>native</library>`.

The problem is that generated blocks use Jackson for deserialization and try to deserialize body's InputStream even when Content-Length is zero which gives error `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input`

It is unfortunately not possible to configure Jackson's ObjectMapper to return null when reading these received empty InputStreams.

Is it possible to generate a client that will handle these cases with empty bodies without exceptions?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26926871/3651739

Comment: @JishnuPrathap Not in my case, I've already tried configuring ObjectMapper. Jackson cannot parse empty objects.